# Why am I getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED?

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, web-hosting

This site funfirstnursery.ae is the one that I simply can't fix this problem of the err_name_not_resolved.

This error started to appear after my hosting accounts memory got full but i made some space. all my other sites are running except this.

I don’t know where is the problem.

Comment: That's nothing to do with WordPress, rather it means that the DNS entry for your domain name can't find the server. If it was working before, I suggest you reach out to your web hosting company.

Comment: Please, take the [tour].

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that the problem i had was coming from my domain registrar(Account).
the domain wasn't pointing to my host account ip as it should.

**the solutions was to**

Remove then Re-add the domain to my hosting account, then lock the domain from my domain registrar's Account.

this Worked for me